# MySQL Combining Two Select Commands - Sum and Group By

Tags: mysql

Table Standings

```
**Season   Owner   Week   Points  Comment**
2013     A       1      5       Excellent
2013     A       2      9       Bad
2013     B       1      4       Ok
2013     B       2      5       Good
```

I am trying to get the following outcome (below) from the table (above) using Mysql query. I want to show the latest week's comment and the sum of the points.

```
Season   Owner   Points   Comment
2013     A       14       Bad
2013     B       9        Good
```

The following (below) gets me the correct grouping and total, but the comment is not from the latest week. Ideas?

```
Select Owner, sum(Points), Comment FROM Standings WHERE Season=2014 GROUP BY Owner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` method:

```
Select Owner, sum(Points),
       substring_index(group_concat(Comment order by week desc), ',', 1) as LastComment
FROM Standings
WHERE Season = 2014
GROUP BY Owner ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case for the old `CONCAT-MAX-SUBSTR` trick!

```
SELECT
  Season, Owner,
  SUM(Points) AS Points,
  SUBSTR(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(WEEK, 5, '0'),Comment)),6,100) AS Comment
FROM standings
GROUP BY Season, Owner
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a97119/3/0)

Comment: Thanks for the help! This worked but i have multiple seasons in the table (which i may not been clear about).